# How to get row for every first occurrence of a column value

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table named `lists` having below columns and rows.

```
   type     | time | alt_id       
------------+------+---------
 invest_fees| t1   |  5601
 invest_fees| t2   |  5601
 invest_fees| t3   |  5601
 countries  | t4   |  5601
 invest_fees| t5   |  5601
 invest_fees| t6   |  5601
 countries  | t7   |  5601
 countries  | t8   |  5601
 invest_fees| t9   |  5602
 countries  | t10  |  5602
```

I want to get this:

```
      type     | time | alt_id       
------------+------+---------
 invest_fees| t1   |  5601
 countries  | t4   |  5601
 invest_fees| t5   |  5601
 countries  | t7   |  5601
 invest_fees| t9   |  5602
 countries  | t10  |  5602
```

i.e. first occurrence of `type` every time it is found.
Later, I want to find out the diff: t4-t1, t7-t5, t10-t9.
Any ideas on how can I achieve this using sql?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your dbms name

Comment: How do you decide the order? Do you have a timestamp or sequence order column as well?

Comment: You need a column to order the rows. Otherwise there is no way to tell if      `d3 | invest_fees` is before or after ` f1 | countries`.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "first" row unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: @Fahmi It is MySQL

Comment: Updated the table values with added columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySQL 8.0+ you can use [`LAG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag):

```
SELECT t.type, t.time, t.alt_id
FROM (SELECT *, LAG(type) OVER() prev FROM tablename) t
WHERE t.prev IS NULL OR t.prev <> t.type
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uQtuVqZR4aHrNpAjZz8szG/1).
For previous versions use variables:

```
SET @rn := 0;
SET @type := null;
SELECT t.type, t.time, t.alt_id 
FROM (
  SELECT @rn := case 
    WHEN @type = type then @rn + 1 
    ELSE 1
  END AS rn, type, time, alt_id,
  @type := type  
  FROM tablename 
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uQtuVqZR4aHrNpAjZz8szG/4).
Results:

```
| type        | time | alt_id |
| ----------- | ---- | ------ |
| invest_fees | t1   | 5601   |
| countries   | t4   | 5601   |
| invest_fees | t5   | 5601   |
| countries   | t7   | 5601   |
| invest_fees | t9   | 5602   |
| countries   | t10  | 5602   |
```